# If I download Ubuntu, with CD, or Windows Installer, will it automatically dual-boot?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

So I want to install Ubuntu, just to learn how to use Linux. Currently I'm using Windows 7 and I have ample HDD space. If I burn this OS onto a CD, or use the WI, will it erase Windows or cause Windows problems? Or will it give me a dual boot option at the beginning of the boot.

Answer (score 1):

During the installation process for Ubuntu, you get to choose "alongside" the existing Windows system, or "something else" where you can manually set up individual disk partitions.  This usually requires shrinking the Windows partition and then creating a separate partition for Ubuntu in the (now) unallocated space.  See for example: http://techsultan.com/install-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot-windows-7-8/

Answer (score 0):

During installation you will get the option to install Ubuntu "alongside" Windows. Click it and go with the flow. Don't disturb partitions if you don't know exactly what are you doing. Windows 7 has 'ntfs' file format which is different from Ubuntu. Disturbing the partitions may cause data loss. Ubuntu will automatically configure the partitions for you.

Comment: any time you make changes to a hard drive like this you should ALWAYS BACK UP YOUR DATA before you do anything else. Make sure you have all of your important data saved elsewhere so that you can recover if something goes awry.